# KeyCode and keyboard layout and language

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown, keycode

I need to include the *asterisk* as an allowable entry on a text box.

How can I test for this key under the KeyDown event regardless of the keyboard layout and language?

Ignoring the numeric keypad, with the Portuguese QWERTY layout this key can be tested through  `Keys.Shift | Keys.Oemplus`. But that will not be the case for other layouts or languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in keydown event get charecter in different language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110073/in-keydown-event-get-charecter-in-different-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong event, you should be using KeyPressed.  That fires when the user presses actual typing keys.  KeyDown is useless here, the virtual key gets translated to a typing key according to the keyboard layout.  Hard to guess what that might be unless you translate the keystroke yourself.  That's hard.

Some code:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  string allowed = "0123456789*\b";
  if (allowed.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) < 0) e.Handled = true;
}
```

The \b is required to allow the user to backspace.

Comment: I'm using the KeyPress event to handle this. Was wondering about the possibility of using KeyDown instead. But your answer reveals it's not possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use KeyPress event

```
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        int keyValue = e.KeyChar;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToChar(keyValue).ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        InitializeComponent();

        //SET FOCUS ON label1 AND HIDE IT
        label1.Visible = false;
        label1.Select();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        int keyValue = e.KeyChar;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToChar(keyValue).ToString();

        if (keyValue == 13) // DETECT "ENTER"
        {
        StreamWriter writelog = File.AppendText(@"C:\keylogger.log");
        writelog.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        writelog.Close();
        }
        else
        {
        StreamWriter writelog = File.AppendText(@"C:\keylogger.log");
        writelog.Write(Convert.ToChar(keyValue).ToString());
        writelog.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please think about improving your answer by adding some description on why this will work. Code dumps are rarely ever a use

Comment: That said, it is still an attempt to answer the question - [somebody must have flagged this post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11164679) for it to appear in the review queue.