# How do I use the Keydown event to get the correct character in multiple languages/keyboard layouts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use keydown event in jquery, but the problem it's stateless for input  language. It's can't determine the input is in English language or in Hebrew or Arabic...?
it returns only keycode, and I can't get character.

Is there any solution??

Comment: There's a jQuery plugin to [determine a browser's language setting](https://github.com/dansingerman/jQuery-Browser-Language). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference) SO thread. Then you can figure out the keyboard code for the character you want in each langauge.

Comment: I think the plugin is not solve the problem. the user can change language during typing. so, i cannt get the right char input by user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To determine the actual character, you should use the [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event instead of `keydown`. While `keydown` provides you with a key code, `keypress` indicates the character which was entered by the user.

Another difference is that when the user presses and holds a key, a `keydown` event is triggered only once, but separate `keypress` events are triggered for each inserted character.

Here's an example of using the `keypress` event:

```
<body>
<form>
  <input id="target" type="text" />
</form>

<script src="http://api.jquery.com/scripts/events.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#target").keypress(function(event) {
    var charCode = event.which; // charCode will contain the code of the character inputted
    var theChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode); // theChar will contain the actual character
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: This worked for me. It picked up both Norwegian characters and then Arabic characters after changing the keyboard layout (while staying on the page - no reload inbetween). [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvywU/)

Answer (score 0):

Dmytro's approach is currently considered deprecated, as indicated in the official Mozilla documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which). Unfortunately, relying on it may not be the best choice.

A more modern and recommended approach is to utilize the `event.code` method to achieve the same result, specifically capturing the "KeyM" key press:

```js
body.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.code === "KeyM") {
    // The 'M' key has been pressed
  }
})
```

By embracing this method, you ensure compatibility and adhere to the latest best practices in web development.

Comment: How does this apply to non-QWERTY (or non-English) layouts? i.e. JCUKEN for Cyrillic languages