# jquery - not able to catch `@` (at the rate symbol) on keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have in my code a `keyup` event and I need to catch the `@` character. I'm using this code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#textbox").keyup(function(e) {
    var keynum = e.keyCode;
    if (keynum && e.shiftKey && keynum == 50) {
      // Made a small change.
      console.log("You pressed @ and value is: " + e.target.value);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textbox" />
```

Now, the problem is that it doesn't work whenever user types `shift+2` a little faster

**EDIT**

You can reproduce this problem by releasing the modifier (shift key) a few milliseconds before the other (2 on my keyboard) key, i.e typing `shift + 2` really fast.

@ConstantinGroß was able to address this problem and has a workaround. Please check the accepted answer below.

Comment: Er... Your code actually works.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Not on a non-English keyboard layout.

Comment: It may not be a safe assumption that `@` requires the shift key on all keyboards.

Comment: It usually works, but fast typing can cause it to miss. I can repro on an English keyboard by releasing shift just before I release 2

Comment: I'm using french layout and `@` is alt gr+0

Comment: An alternative might be to check every keyup event and compare the position of the caret and the preceding character. I assume you're making some sort of twitter style @ system right?

Comment: @JayWadhwa I guess the situation here is a non-English keyboard?

Comment: On a non english keyboard the `@` symbol isn't going to map to the keycode `50`, it's a different key...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in keydown event get charecter in different language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110073/in-keydown-event-get-charecter-in-different-language)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does indeed seem to be an issue with jQuery detecting multi-key characters when they are done too fast (e.g. releasing the modifier key just a few milliseconds before the other key). I was able to reproduce this on my Germany keyboard layout as well, where `@` is `AltGr+Q`. Here's another solution keeping track of the number of times the `@` character occurs in the input value. Not very elegant, but it does the trick reliably for me.

```js
$("#textbox").keyup(function(e) {
  // if content is empty reset at-count
  if('' === $(this).val().trim()) {
     $(this).data('at-count', 0);
  }
  // removing all characters other than @, then counting the length
  var atCount = $(this).val().replace(/[^@]/g, "").length;
  // if the number of @ in the input value has increased:
  if (atCount > ($(this).data('at-count') || 0)) {
    console.log("You pressed @ and value is: " + e.target.value);
  }
  // store the current @ count for later comparison
  $(this).data('at-count', atCount);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textbox" />
```

Comment: By the way, I tried the following based on the accepted answer of the [question linked as possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110073/in-keydown-event-get-charecter-in-different-language): Using `keypress` instead of `keyup` in conjunction with `if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) === "@") { ... }` - but it failed for me trying it with the Chinese Pinyin input method under Windows, while my solution keeps working even then.

Comment: but I still don't understand; if we're releasing the shift key a few milliseconds earlier than how come my system prints `@` and not `2`?

Comment: I guess the OSes (or maybe even the keyboard hardware itself) implement some kind of "cooldown phase" for modifier keys exactly for that purpose, because you would quite often mistype otherwise.

Comment: I've edited your question to fix a small bug. It won't work if you remove everything from the textarea and type `@`.

Comment: Strange, that should have worked without that change, because the @ count is 0 already when the value is empty. I had edited the answer yesterday to fix a similar issue, maybe you didn't have the latest version of the code. I'll check once I'm back at my work station.

Answer (score 4):

You could use KeyboardEvent.key (e.key vs e.keyCode):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

```js
$("#textbox").keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.key === '@') {
    console.log("You pressed @ and value is: " + e.target.value);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textbox" />
```

Comment: It's jQuery code, and that library normalizes the event attributes so that `keyCode` is reliable.

Comment: @Tanner, I'm not sure why I saw someone down-vote your answer almost as soon as it appeared. Even if jQuery "normalizes the event attributes", using `key` is good practice as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: OP is using jQuery, so where's the problem?

Comment: this should be the right answer, but believe me it still doesn't work for me

Comment: I'm console logging the `e.key`, upon doing it slowly I get `@` but faster I get `Shift` even though textbox prints @ in there

Comment: I was able to reproduce this on my German keyboard as well, where it's `AltGr+Q`. If you're too fast, the detection won't work. I've come up with a solution in my own answer.

Comment: @JayWadhwa you're right, looks like the issue persists. How does Constantin's answer work for you?